# Is it unprofessional to move because someone near you is making a distracting noise?

Tags: professionalism, communication, distractions

Many things I can ignore: people clicking pens, frequent coughing and loud sneezing etc. However I found it unbearable when the person in front of me cleared his throat every 60 seconds. It was very loud, disgusting and distracting. I never met him before, and had no idea who he was. We don't have assigned desks at work, and just go to whichever is available.

My work place keeps a very close eye on it's employees, and we have to send an email out to a couple people if we need to log off early/unexpectedly. I sent the email, and said I had to move desks because a person near me is making a distracting noise and I couldn't focus, and got the ok.

Was this the right thing to do? I noticed I was distracted enough that I was making mistakes, but I may have been able to tune out the sound after 20 minutes. Would it have been better to address the issue with the person himself? I'm in no way trying to get him in trouble, I realize he may have allergies or something.

Comment: At lot of times people do things that annoy others and they are unaware of it. Just a brief comment might do the trick.

Comment: I'm befuddled about a point. You log on and can't log off until quitting time? Good computer security says that you log off if you need to leave, like using the bathroom.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You did the right thing for four reasons :

- You did not enter into conflict with the individual
- You addressed a workplace problem to management rather than colleagues
- You put the company first, avoiding personal issues
- You acted in response to a problem in efficiency

At the end of the day, companies need the job done and avoidance of conflict is always best.

Answer (score 5):

> Was this the right thing to do?

Yes, it was exactly the right thing to do - you solved the problem with minimum fuss, and got on with it.

If you'd have spoken to him directly, then that could have easily resulted in an awkward conversation at best, or an unnecessary confrontation at worst. If there was really no alternative then you may have had to speak to him, but you were absolutely correct in looking to move desks as a first port of call.

Answer (score 0):

> My work place keeps a very close eye on it's employees, and we have to
>   send an email out to a couple people if we need to log off
>   early/unexpectedly. I sent the email, and said I had to move desks
>   because a person near me is making a distracting noise and I couldn't
>   focus, and got the ok.
>
> Was this the right thing to do?

Since you specifically got the okay from your company, then it was the right thing to do.